# Do Jammers disable ALL enemy equipment?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I recently noticed in Black Ops that Jammers are the bee's knees for flushing out campers. If you can't reach a claymore with a flashbang, then just set a jammer somewhere close.

I noticed though that I didn't get shot by a Cobra while in the radius of my Jammer(and I didn't have Ghost Pro). So does the Jammer disable ALL enemy equipment including kill streaks? Also, does it disable RC-XDs?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that jammers don't protect you from enemy air support. If you think about it, the jammer can't reach the chopper anyways, so why would it affect it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jammer disables claymores, sentry guns, and SAM turrets. It disables the radar and voice notifications of enemies in the vicinity of the jammer. It doesn't completely disable the RC-XD, but it messes with their speed and steering.

As far as I know, it *doesn't* prevent you from getting shot by helicopters.